# How to Install OS level dependencies in lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-ami

I want my lambda function to have *libssl-dev* and *libffi-dev* dependencies.

There are ways to install language-specific dependencies(pip and npm) in ZIP file.

But is including OS-specific dependencies possible like running a shell script to include in lambda layer?

Looking for solutions *preferably* without involving docker or steps to modify existing AMIs with these dependencies.

Comment: You can use `yumdownloader`. Take a look at [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-linux-binary-package/?nc1=h_ls) example.